# Need to sum all Most Recent Rows from each Store that have ItemID

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with, among other things, these columns: `DateTransferred, ComputedQuantity, StoreID, ItemID`

I have two goals. My simpler goal is to write a query where I feel in the ItemID and it sums up the ComputedQuantity where it matches that ItemID, only using the most recent DateTransferred for each StoreID. So with the following example data:

```
DateTransferred | StoreID | ItemID | ComputedQuantity
11/10/17        | 1       | 1      | 3 <
10/10/17        | 1       | 1      | 4
09/10/17        | 2       | 1      | 9 <
08/10/17        | 3       | 1      | 1 <
07/10/17        | 3       | 1      | 10
```

I would want it to pull every row with `<` next to it, as that's the most recent Date for that StoreID, and sum up to 13

My more complicated goal is that I would like to include the above-calculated value into a 'join' where I'm dealing with the Item table, so that I can pull all the items and join them with a new column which has the summed up ComputedQuantity

This is on SQL Server 10 on Windows Server 2008, if that matters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple method uses a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t. DateTransferred = (select max(t2.DateTransferred)
                            from t t2 
                            where t2.storeid = t.storeid
                           );
```

Another even simpler method uses window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by storeid order by DateTransferred desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

In either case, you can add a `where` clause to the subquery if you want the most recent date on or before some given date (say a year ago).

Also, these both assume that your data has no future dates.  If so, then add `where DateTransferred < getdate()`.

Comment: use the row_number answer but add DESC in order by.  Also if you need more than one item per store you can add to the partition by storeID,ItemID

Comment: neither of these answers are giving me what i want. The first answer I can't understand, it looks like there are 2 tables, t and t2, but I haven't mentioned having 2 tables with a StoreID column each. The second answer seems to only return a single row (not a sum at all) for each StoreID, the oldest row for that StoreID, completely disregarding ItemID altogether.

Comment: I used @KeithL advice to modify the second statement. I'm still not quire sure how I could include it in a JOIN with the Item table, not even sure if that's possible. I've posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The final statement which sums the ComputedQuantities:

```
select ItemID, SUM(ComputedQuantity) Quantity
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by StoreID, ItemID order by DateTransferred DESC) as seqnum
      from [db].[dbo].[InventoryTransferLog] t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1 and ComputedQuantity > 0
GROUP BY ItemID
ORDER BY ItemID
```

I decided not to sum values < 0

Comment: There is no need for sum or group as subquery can only return one seqnum =1. Also if you want item info you can add after subquery. Join item on t.itemid=item.itemid

Comment: I did need the sum and group to make it work. There are supposed to be more seqnum = 1 for each itemID -- 1 for each store. That was the idea -- to sum up the latest one for each store.